# Using Web.Win.Sockets in C++ Builder 10 Seattle

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10-seattle

I have an existing (large) project that was originally built using **C++ Builder 2010**. It uses the now deprecated sockets for communication.

I [read](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Working_with_Sockets_Index) that they were still available in a sample project and built it from the command line. I navigated to the the bpl in the sample folder from **Component/Install Packages** and installed it and went on to try and get the code going. But I get a feeling some step is missing.

Including **Web.Win.Sockets.hpp** from the sample folder does not seem to be enough. It seems to not contain definitions regarding a lot of things, like for example **TServerSocket** etc that the existing code uses.
**System.Win.ScktComp** seems to include these missing definitions but mixing both doesn't seem like the right thing to do. Just for fun I tried some crazy thing like that once and got it to compile, but data transmitted seemed to include garbage that messed up the communication.

At one point I tried moving to the components in **System.Win.ScktComp** instead but there was no good info about what correlated to what and if there were any caveats. After I got the program to compile it would not be able to connect etc.

So, is there any good guide to enabling and using the "old" sockets for **C++ Builder 10 Seattle**? And if one were to move to the new ones, is it a drop in replacement or would it require a lot of work? The system transmits a lot of data in a custom binary format so a lot of stream handling is done etc. Right now I need to get this up and running so a large re-write of those parts is not feasible at this moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Web.Win.Sockets` and `System.Win.ScktComp` are not the same thing, and are not drop-in replacements for each other.

`System.Win.ScktComp` contains the old VCL socket components (`TClientSocket`, `TServerSocket`, etc).  This is the one you want.

`Web.Win.Sockets` contains the old CLX socket components (`TTcpClient`, `TTcpServer`, etc).  You don't want this one, so ignore the sample project, you don't need it.

To get the VCL sockets components, all you need to do is install the `dclSockets` package that is in your `$(BDS)\bin` folder, like the documentation says:

[Installing Socket Components](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Installing_Socket_Components)

> The socket components are not installed by default. To use the socket components, you must install the **dclsockets<.bpl>** package.
>
> **To install the socket components:**
>
> 1. Select **Component > [Install Packages](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Install_Packages)**.
> 2. In the **Install Packages** dialog box, click Add.
> 3. In the **Add Design Package** dialog, browse to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\bin`.
> 4. Select **dclsockets230.bpl**, and click Open.
> 5. Click OK to dismiss **Install Packages** dialog.
> 6. The socket components ([TClientSocket](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Win.ScktComp.TClientSocket) and [TServerSocket](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Win.ScktComp.TServerSocket)) are listed in the **Internet** category of the **Tool Palette**.
>
> **Note:** These steps are one-time installation instructions. The socket components should be available for all future projects.

If you want to switch your code to different socket components in the future, you will have to re-write your socket code accordingly.

Comment: I somehow knew you would answer. Whenever I finally get an answer to a RAD Studio or C++ Builder question it's you :). Big thanks to your efforts. Just a bit sad that it's not as easy to get a lot of feedback as it is for Visual C++ for example. Anyway, for some reason they seem to be using both TServerSocket AND **TTcpServer** in the code. From what I can see it looks like the **TTcpServer** is used when setting the port to check that it's available. It starts listening to it and then throws an error if `Listening` is false and if true, sets `active` to false.

Comment: Is there "any" differences with the dclsockets version shipped with Seattle and 2010? Communication seems to have extra data in it when it's received and digested. There's no real good way of debugging and looking at the data sent and what it conatains in the IDE. Some visualizer for streams or something would have been great for this.

Comment: I found a piece of code that is supposed to get almost entirely string data and present that "as is" and it's showing me a lot of Japanese characters. So I would instinctively say that something is messed up with encoding. But since nothing has changed in the code I'm wondering if anything has changed in the strings handling sin 2010? Mostly AnsiStrings are used internally.

Comment: Code should not be mixing `TServerSocket` and `TTcpServer` together. There is no reason to use `TTcpServer` to check for port availability, `TServerSocket` can do the same thing. In any case, the socket components do not handle Unicode strings correctly. If you are seeing Japanese-like characters, you definitely have an encoding mismatch. I don't recommend using the `SendText()` and `ReceiveText()` methods in D2009 onwards, it is better to use `SendBuf()` and `ReceiveBuf()` directly instead and handle byte<->string conversions manually in code.

Comment: Yea, I did rewrite the code that checked for free sockets to use TServerSocket instead. The functions you mention for sending text are not used. Instead there are overloaded stream operators for AnsiString and other types that I writes the underlying data using WriteBuffer of TStream. Looking closer at it the correct data seem to be written to the stream and received by the client when I check in the overloaded stream operators. But somehow once it get propagated through the system, code that previously worked must now act to corrupt it somehow.

Comment: Sounds like it is happening outside of your socket code, and outside the scope of this question.

Comment: True indeed. Do you know of anything that could have changed it's default behavior since 2010 that could be part of the culprit?

Comment: The RTL's String handling has not changed since 2009.  But the `dclSocket` components have changed a few times after 2009 to try to account for Unicode, before they finally just gave up. But that only applies to the `(Send/Receive)Text()` methods. The rest of the socket component code has not changed in years. So something else has likely changed elsewhere in your code. You will just have to debug it to see what is really happening.